# Android updating database record always returns zero

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sqlite

My Update method in DataBaseHandler Class

```
    public void updateProject(Project project){
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(PROJECT_NAME, project.getName()); // Contact Name
         values.put(PROJECT_DESCRIPTION, project.getDescription()); // Contact Phone
         values.put(CLIENT_NAME, project.getClient_name());
         values.put(LOCATION, project.getLocation());
         String where = PROJECT_ID + " = ? ";       
         String [] value = { String.valueOf(project.getProject_id()) };
         try{
             int count = db.update(TABLE_PROJECT, values, where , value);
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Updated rows -> " + count);
         }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.close();
    }
}
```

The java bean class

```
public class Project implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int project_id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String client_name;
    private String location;

    public Project(){

    }

    public Project(int project_id, String name, String client_name,String description, String location){
        this.project_id = project_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.client_name = client_name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public int getProject_id() {
        return project_id;
    }

    public void setProject_id(int project_id) {
        this.project_id = project_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getClient_name() {
        return client_name;
    }

    public void setClient_name(String client_name) {
        this.client_name = client_name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

}
```

The activity which adds and updates the project item from list view

```
public class AddProjectActivity extends Activity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private MenuItem saveItem;
    private DatabaseHandler dbHelper;
    private static final String TITLE = "Add Project";
    public boolean isEdit = false;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "debugger";
    private Project editedProject;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_project);
        setTitle(TITLE);
        dbHelper = DatabaseHandler.getInstance(this);           

        //get intent from Project Fragment when project is edited
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.hasExtra(IntentConstants.PROJECT_ITEM)){
            Project project = (Project) intent.getSerializableExtra(IntentConstants.PROJECT_ITEM);
            if(project != null){
                this.isEdit = true;
                setEditedProject(project);
                setProjectData(project);
            }
        }
    }          



    private void setProjectData(Project project){
        EditText projectName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectName);
        projectName.setText(project.getName());
        EditText clientName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectClient);
        clientName.setText(project.getClient_name());
        EditText projectDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectDesc);
        projectDesc.setText(project.getDescription());
        EditText projectLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectLocation);
        projectLocation.setText(project.getLocation());
    }



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.saveButton:
           if(isEdit == true){
              updateProject();
           }else{
              saveProject();
           }
           finish();
        break;
     case R.id.cancelButton:
        finish();
        break;
     default:
        break;
    }
 return true;
}

    private void updateProject(){
      dbHelper.updateProject(getProjectData(getEditedProject()));
    }

    public boolean isEdit() {
        return isEdit;
    }

    public void setEdit(boolean isEdit) {
        this.isEdit = isEdit;
    }

    private Project getProjectData(Project newProject){
        EditText projectName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectName);
        String project = projectName.getText().toString();
        EditText clientName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectClient);
        String client = clientName.getText().toString();
        EditText projectDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectDesc);
        String description = projectDesc.getText().toString();
        EditText projectLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProjectLocation);
        String location = projectLocation.getText().toString();

        newProject.setName(project);
        newProject.setClient_name(client);
        newProject.setDescription(description);
        newProject.setLocation(location);
        return newProject;
    }

    public Project getEditedProject() {
        return editedProject;
    }

    public void setEditedProject(Project editedProject) {
        this.editedProject = editedProject;
    }

}
```

My `ListFragment` method that handles the click of listview item. It passes the data to `AddProjectActivity` using `Intent`

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if(dbHelper != null){
            Project project = (Project) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddProjectActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(IntentConstants.PROJECT_ITEM, project);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.isEdit = true;
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is when listview item is edited and updated by user it never gets updated in database. The rowcount returned by update method is always zero.

I am not able to fix this issue.

Can someone help please.

Comment: post only relavant code. Not your whole project.

Comment: Is that the full code for the `AddProjectActivity` activity? I don't see anywhere in your code where you call the `updateProject()` method.

Comment: I have posted it please check.

Comment: This problem is hard to be debugged by us. Did you checked the `PROJECT_ID` used in the `updateProject` method? Did you list the values in the database to see if the id exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I wasn't setting the id of Project object in ListView. So the id was never matched and nothing was updated.